# Getting error while running the aggregate method of MognoDB

Tags: mongodb, aggregate

I am getting the following error while joining two collection and project the fields using MognoDB.

> Error::

```
Error: command failed: {
    "ok" : 0,
    "errmsg" : "'pipeline' option must be specified as an array",
    "code" : 14,
    "codeName" : "TypeMismatch"
} : aggregate failed
```

I am explaining my query below.

```
db.getCollection('orderproductsreport').aggregate([
    {
          $match: {
              "Customer.StoreCode":"CMHB",
               OrderStatus: 'Created',
              'Customer.Children.StudentGrade': 'Grade 1',
               OrderType: 'Online',
          }
    },
    {
        $lookup:{
            from: "orders",
            as: "PaymentInfo",
            let: { OrderNumber: '$OrderNumber' },
            pipeline: {
                $match: {
                    $expr: {
                        $and: [
                            { $eq: ['$OrderNumber', '$$OrderNumber'] },
                            { $eq: ['$PaymentStatus', 'Payment Received'] },
                        ]
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    },
    {
        $project:{
            "OrderNumber":1,
            "OrderStatus":1,
            "OrderType":1,
            "OrderCreatedAt": { $dateToString: { format: "%Y-%m-%d", date: "$OrderCreatedAt" } },
            "StoreCode":1,
            "ProductName":1,
            "SKU":1,
            "CategoryInfo.category.CategoryName":1,
            "Customer.CustomerMobile":1,
            "Customer.CustomerFirstName":1,
            "Customer.CustomerLastName":1,
            "Customer.Children.StudentAdmissionID":1,
            "MRP":1,
            "GST":1,
            "TotalDiscountPrice":1,
            "PaymentInfo.PaymentDetails.TransactionId":1,
            "PaymentInfo.PaymentDetails.PaymentAmount":1,
            "PaymentInfo.PaymentDetails.PaymentStatus":1,

        }
    }
])
```

Here I need to join two collection `i.e-orderproductsreport and orders` and the common filed for both collection is `OrderNumber`. I have to also match `order collection` `PaymentInfo.PaymentDetails.PaymentStatus` value with user input value along with rest match conditions. But As per my query its throwing error. I need to resolve this error and fetch the required record.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [aggregate](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.aggregate/) method, not `find`.

Comment: Oh....sorry. I used aggregate but still the result is not coming. I updated my post. Please check it.

Comment: Yes I changed bit still error is `errmsg" : "'OrderNumber' starts with an invalid character for a user variable name",`

Comment: Try lower case for variable names.

Answer (score 0):

Change the `pipeline` arg from an object to an array:

```js
pipeline: { // No
                $match: {
                    ...
                }
            }
```

to

```js
pipeline: [   // YES
                {$match: {
                    ...
                }}
          ]
```